# How to use Range with Variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

i was doing a **For Next Loop** while i encountered this problem using a range syntax:

```
For count=0 to lastline
.
.
.
*Range("A"& count+4 : "G"&count+4)* **Error here**
```

I would like to make a normal range like for example Range("A23:A26") but defined with the variable (count + 4).

Maybe it is a syntax error, but i cant find the solution.

I appreciate your time!

Comment: `Range("A" & count + 4 & ":G" & count + 4)`  The `:` is part of the string.  And there needs to be a space before and after the `&`.

Comment: And how can i select this range with variables: Range("A4:C4,I4:M4").  I transform the syntax and there is sintax error with this: Range(""A" & Count & ":C" & Count,"I" & Count & ":M" & Count").Select